# For most directions does the supporting hyperplane meeting a bounded convex set meet it in one point?

Tags: convex-geometry, convexity, convex-analysis

Let $C\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be non-empty, convex and compact. For $v\in S^{n-1}$, let $H_v$ be the supporting hyperplane in the direction of $v$ (i.e., $H_v$ is the boundary of the smallest closed half-space with outward normal $v$ that contains $C$). Let $U\subseteq S^{n-1}$ be the set of directions $v$ such that $H_v$ meets $C$ at exactly one point.

**Main question:** Does $S^{n-1}\backslash U$ have measure zero?

If not, then I have a second question: Is $U$ dense in $S^{n-1}$?

For $n=2$, it's easy to see that $S^{n-1}\backslash U$ is countable (otherwise there are uncountably many nondegenerate line segments in the boundary of $C$, and hence $C$ has infinite perimeter). But a cylinder shows that in general $S^{n-1}\backslash U$ need not be countable.

Comment: Does a general version of your argument show that the boundary of $C$ would have positive (Lebesgue) measure if $S^{n-1}\setminus U$ doesn't have measure zero?

Comment: doesn't the result follow from the fact that the support function is lipschitz so it is differentiable almost everywhere?

Comment: @alesia: Yup, that looks like the answer to my question. Why don't you write it up as an official answer?

Comment: @alesia I do not see how differentiability  would imply the result. A convex function $f(x,y)=x^2$ is differentiable everywhere yet, at every point, the supporting hyperplane meets the graph along a line. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: alesia may be thinkng of something like Theorem 1.1 here: http://www.oyama.e.u-tokyo.ac.jp/notes/diffSuppFunc01.pdf   The graph of your f(x,y) is not compact. If you restrict to a compact domain, then there are two ways of relevant ways of counting: by counting the normals and by counting the contact points. If you count contact points, you are right. But in my question, I am counting the normals.

Comment: I do not think that Theorem 1.1 you mentioned answers your question. I think it says that the function is differentiable iff the supporting hyperplane is unique and that does not mean that the supporting hyperplane is tangent to the set at one point. I think you question is more difficult than that. It is a very good question and I am thrilled to see a solution.

Comment: Change the title to a short and catchy one if you want more attention to your question. The question deserves it.

Comment: I don't see the difficulty. Work with the convex support function (Thm 1.1 is about the concave one, but we can replace $p$ with $-p$) $\sigma_C(p) = \sup_{x\in C} p\cdot x$. Then Thm 1.1 says that iff $\sigma_C$ is differentiable at $p$, there is a unique $x\in C$ with $\sigma_C(p)=p\cdot x$. But for all $y\in C$ we have $p\cdot y \le \sigma_C(p)$. So the only point $y$ of $C$ such that $p\cdot x=p\cdot y$ is $y=x$. So the only contact point between $H_p$ and $C$ is $x$. What am I missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139765/discussion-between-piotr-hajlasz-and-alexander-pruss).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The support function of $C$, restricted to the unit sphere, is differentiable exactly at directions such that (the relevant) hyperplane normal to that direction has a single contact point with $C$.

Because $C$ is bounded, its support function is Lipschitz. Rademacher's theorem then says it is differentiable almost everywhere, giving a positive answer to the question.

Comment: The assumption that $C$ is bounded is not needed. Even if $C$ is unbounded, its boundary is locally Lipschitz and therefore by Rademacher's theorem, is locally differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: If $C$ is not bounded, $H_v$ might not be defined.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see.

Comment: @DeaneYang I posted an answer which gives a much stronger result.

Answer (score 7):

This is a consequence of the following result from

[image]

*Ewald, G.; Larman, D. G.; Rogers, C. A.*, [**The directions to the line segments and of the r-dimensional balls on the boundary of a convex body in Euclidean space**](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0025579300002655), Mathematika, Lond. 17, 1-20 (1970). [ZBL0199.57002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0199.57002).

The above statement is copied from the monograph.

*Schneider, Rolf*, [**Convex bodies: the Brunn-Minkowski theory**](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139003858), Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications 151. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-107-60101-7/hbk; 978-1-139-00385-8/ebook). xxii, 736 p. (2014). [ZBL1287.52001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1287.52001).